# How to reconstruct array from string representation of array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv

I've got a huge CSV that was generated by a Python script. Some cells include arrays of data, while others include single-item arrays. Some examples:

```
cell01 == ['"July, 2002"', 'CUREE Publication No. CEA-01.', 'Project No. 3126', 'Prepared for Consortium of Universities for Research in Earthquake Engineering.']
cell02 == ['[Memorandum from Ralph J. Johnson on Andy Place].']
cell03 == ["Financial statements for the years ended March 31, 1991 and 1990 and independent auditors' report"]
```

Ideally, I'd like to parse all this data into structures that look like the following:

```
cell01_parsed[0] == '"July, 2002"'
cell01_parsed[1] == 'CUREE Publication No. CEA-01.'
cell01_parsed[2] == 'Project No. 3126'
cell01_parsed[3] == 'Prepared for Consortium of Universities for Research in Earthquake Engineering.'

cell02_parsed == '[Memorandum from Ralph J. Johnson on Andy Place].'

cell03_parsed == 'Financial statements for the years ended March 31, 1991 and 1990 and independent auditors\' report'
```

However, when I use a `csv.reader()` or `csv.DictReader()`, these lines are parsed as strings, not arrays. What would be an easy way to do this? I can't use `split(',')` since some of the strings have commas in the middle of items.

Comment: [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) will preserve quoted characters...

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. I just used `csv.writer()` to write out the data from the first code section and read it back using `csv.reader()`. The result was exactly like you expected it to be. I think there is something you haven't explained getting in the way. How is the data written?

Comment: I was using `csv.DictWriter()` originally since all of the data had up to 31 columns, but not exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split your strings by regex (find out one that fits your data) like so:

```py
import re
test_str = '"July, 2002", CUREE Publication No. CEA-01.' 
re.compile(',(?!.+\")').split(test_str)
```

Comment: I've got a considerable amount of data to process (15k rows, 31 columns), so I fear regex may mess up/misinterpret some data. I think I'll go with `shlex.split()` as @pycoder suggester